# Как отобразить данные из БД SQLite в QTableView в измененном виде, не меняя значений в БД

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

В ***SQLite*** есть таблица `payments`. В ней есть столбец `number`, который хранит данные в виде:

```
[параметр1]=[значение1]
[параметр2]=[значение2]
...
[параметрN]=[значениеN].
```

Разные ячейки данного столбца могут хранить различное количество параметров. Необходимо сделать, чтоб данный столбец отображался в таблице `QTableView` в виде:

```
[значение1], [значение2], ..., [значениеN].
```

Вот мой код, который выводит данные в таблицу:

```
con = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
con.setDatabaseName('data.sqlite')
con.open()
stm = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(parent=myapp)
stm.setTable('payments')
stm.setSort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
stm.select()
model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel() 
model.setQuery("""SELECT * FROM payments""")
model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Номер')
model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Дата')
model.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Сумма')
myapp.ui.paymentsTable.setModel(model)
myapp.ui.paymentsTable.setSelectionBehavior(1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `QItemDelegate` предоставляет средства отображения и редактирования для элементов данных из модели.

Обратите внимание на строку `# self.fillTable()`, раскомментируйте строку, если вам надо создать 
таблицу `payments`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql     import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QTableView, QApplication, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, 
                             QAbstractItemView, QItemDelegate)
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt



class Example(QMainWindow):    

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 180)

        self.createConnection()

#        self.fillTable()                                                   # !!!

        self.createModel()
        self.initUI()

    def createConnection(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('data.sqlite')
        if not self.db.open():
            QMessageBox.critical(None, ("Cannot open database"),
                                       ("Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                                                     "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                                                     "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
                                                     "how to build it.\n\n"
                                                     "Click Cancel to exit."),
                                       QMessageBox.Cancel)
            return False

    def fillTable(self):
        self.db.transaction()
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS payments;")
        query.exec_("CREATE TABLE payments(id int primary key, "
                    "number varchar(20), data varchar(20), suma varchar(20));")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO payments values(1, 'NUMBER=555\nACCOUNT=1', '01', '10');")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO payments values(2, 'NUMBER=111\nACCOUNT=2\nACCOUNT=333',  '02', '5');")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO payments values(3, 'NUMBER=111\nACCOUNT=',  '01', '10');")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO payments values(4, 'NUMBER=333\nACCOUNT=',  '03', '15');")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO payments values(5, 'NUMBER=444\nACCOUNT=1', '04', '1');")
        self.db.commit()

    def createModel(self):
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("payments")
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "id")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Номер")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Дата")
        self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Сумма")
        self.model.select()

    def initUI(self):
        self.view = QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        mode = QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection 
        self.view.setSelectionMode(mode)

        self.view.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ViewDelegate())                # <---    

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view) 

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        if (self.db.open()):
            self.db.close()


class ViewDelegate(QItemDelegate):                                           # <--- 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):    
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)

        myReplace = [ 'NUMBER=', '\nACCOUNT=' ]
        for repl in myReplace:
            if repl == 'NUMBER=':
                value = value.replace(repl, '')
            else:
                value = value.replace(repl, ', ')
        try:
            painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignLeft, "{}".format(value))
        except :
            QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example() 
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]